# What happens if I commit the same files to two different repositories

Tags: git, github

I have a project where I committed the files to a github repo. It worked. Now I want to commit the same files to another repository which is private and outside github.

How should I do it? Now the files have `.git` directories so I suppose that I should copy everything and then delete the `.git` files from the copied project directory?

Or is there some other more appropriate way?

Comment: Just add a new remote to the 'outside' repository and push your stuff to this remote as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A git repository can have more than 1 remote repository. To add a new remote repository use:  `git remote add <name-of-remote> <uri-to-remote>`

Then you can push whatever you'd like to that repository from the existing commits or branches.

`git push -u <name-of-remote> <branch>`

You can list the currently configured remote branches for your current working repository using `git remote -v`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the way you said or you could check if the other project hosting website you are trying to use provides a way to connect your github profile.

Or, you can add another remote and push the required branch to the new website.